# How to get a column value after and count after join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realize this has already been posted somewhere but due to keyword density I cannot find it.

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.*), t1.t2id, t1.c2
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.t2id
GROUP BY t1.t2id
```

Note `t2id` is a `nchar(256)` and t1.c2 is an `ntext`.

So basically I want to count how many t2's there are for each value record in t1 and get some value from t1. Now the problem is that when I execute this in c# I GET the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column 't1.c2' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

But shouldn't the `GROUP BY t1.t2id` ensure that this won't happen?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to have

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.*), t1.t2id, t1.c2 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.t2id 
GROUP BY t1.t2id, t1.c2
```

The r1.c2 isn't in an aggregate (count) or the group by so it needs to go into one.

Edit: deal with t1.c2 being ntext

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.*), t1.t2id, cast(t1.c2 as nvarchar(max))
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.t2id 
GROUP BY t1.t2id, cast(t1.c2 as nvarchar(max))
```

If your c2 column has more content than nvarchar(max) can hold you have a problem, the performance won't be good either but without know how much data you have its hard to say if it will be a problem.

Comment: Hmm that might work but when I do this I get the error that 
Additional information: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. t1.c2 is an ntext that might be a problem?

Comment: Yes, ntext is a pain to work with, you may be able to cast it to nvarchar(max). Grouping by it may be slow though if you have many rows.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that as error message tells you, you need to pass `t1.c2` to `GROUP BY`clause in following:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(t2.*),t1.t2id,t1.c2   FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.t2id GROUP BY t1.t2id, t1.c2";
```

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that all the columns which are not part of aggregate functions should appear in the GROUP BY Clause. You need to add t1.c2 in the group by clause

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.*), t1.t2id, t1.c2
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.t2id
GROUP BY t1.t2id,t1.c2
```